# Mathematica - CSV to Multidimensional Charts

Tags: csv, wolfram-mathematica, data-visualization, multidimensional-array

I have a CSV file with 5 columns and about 2*10<sup>4</sup> rows that I need to visualise.

I've imported the file like so:

```
data = Import["res.csv", "CSV"];`
```

Now, I'm going to want to generate a lot of visuals from this - all 5 dimensions on a single plot as well as various cross sections.

My questions:

If I want to select, say columns 1, 4 and 5 from my data and feed them to `ListPlot3D` how would I do that?

And, values in columns can be grouped. So if I wanted to `ListPlot3D` colums 1, 2, 4 and 5, but I want to group columns 1 and 2 on the same axis, how would I tell Mathematica to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: On second thoughts, assuming that column 1 and 2 are x-axis values, column 4 the y-axis value, and column 5 the z-axis value (which is usually the dependent value) does that mean that two differing sets of x-values give rise to the same set of dependent z-values?

Comment: @Sjoerd, columns 4 and 5 are independent of each other, but both of them are dependant on columns 1, 2 and 3. The first 3 colums are something like: for every col1 value there are 10 col2 values. and for every col2 value there are 100 col3 values.

Comment: Since ListPlot3D requires {x,y,z} triples, you have to describe which columns map to x, y, and z respectively, for each of the two data sets. So may I assume col 4 maps to z for the first set, and col 5 to z for the second set? And the, which columns map to x and  y?

Comment: I just need the syntax for grouping columns, I will figure out what combinations I need. For now lets just say columns 1 and 2 map to X, column 3 is Y and columns 4 and 5 will be Z on individual plots.

Comment: Changed the 2nd part of my code accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate to disagree with a fellow [poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083044/mathematica-csv-to-multidimensional-charts/7083342#7083342) especially after it has been accepted, but the `Transpose` is unnecessary. Almost everything you're asking for can be done within the context of [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html):

```
ListPlot3D[ data[[All, {1, 4, 5}]] ]
```

Since matrices are stored row-wise within Mathematica, `[[All, {1, 4, 5}]]` can be read `[[rows, columns]]`.  More specifically, `All` indicates here that you want all rows, but you can specify specific rows as well.  Another construct that may be of interest is [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Span.html) which is used to specify groups of indices, and if your CSV file contains a header row, you can strip it from your data using

```
ListPlot3D[ data[[ 2 ;; , {1, 4, 5}]] ]
```

As to your second requirement, to use both columns 1 and 2 as the x coordinate, then it is simply

```
ListPlot3D[ {data[[All, {2, 4, 5}]], data[[All, {1, 4, 5}]]} ]
```

and you change `All` to `2;;` if you wish to strip off the header row.

Comment: This is the better syntax. If your data is all numeric, you should do `data=Developer`ToPackedArray[data]` and your subsequent operations should be much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I thought the transpose was a bit much but I wasn't sure. I can plot `ListPointPlot3D`, with all the data, absolutely fine. Mathematica just doesn't want to make a surface out of them. Not sure why `ListPlot3D` wont happen.
@Joshua, should that be `data=DeveloperToPackedArray[data]` ? and will that allow me the use the same syntax as above.

Comment: @Griffin, no, that should be ``Developer`ToPackedArray[data]``; the grave mark was dropped. Also, what does `ListPlot3D` do instead? You could try lowering the `InterpolationOrder` to 1 or 0 to see what happens.

Comment: @rcollyer You're right. I have been doing this so much with separate data arrays (I mean, combining arrays named x, y, z in a list with point triples using `Transpose[{x,y,z}]` that I was to focused now on doing the same here. Not that it's wrong, but it's unnecessarily complicated. I propose Griffin accepts your answer.

Comment: @rcollyer, I set the `InterpolationOrder` to 0, and used the `Developer\`ToPackedArray[data]` and `ListPlot3D` still wasn't giving me an output. It just says "Running..." for ages then the kernel crashes.

Comment: @Griffin, I don't know if sorting the points will help, but try it. It sounds to me like your using to many points for `ListPlot3D`. By any chance, do you have multiple z values for single x-y coordinate? It may be choking on that. In the meantime, I'd try to reduce the number of points, either by rejecting every other one, or getting more creative and using [triangulation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ComputationalGeometry/tutorial/ComputationalGeometry.html).

Comment: Try also setting the `MaxPlotPoints` option in addition to the `InterpolationOrder`.  It'll downsample your data for you.

Comment: @Joshua, I wa not aware of that.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly that would be

```
ListPlot3D[Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 4]], data[[All, 5]]}]]
```

and for the multiple sets:

```
ListPlot3D[
 {
  Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 3]], data[[All, 4]]}],
  Transpose[{data[[All, 2]], data[[All, 3]], data[[All, 5]]}]
  }
 ]
```

Comment: The first line is taking a very long time to run, on a very fast machine. Is this to be expected?

Comment: Well, you asking it to plot 160,000 points. It has to do a triangularization and plot that. Do you really need that much points? The Transpose part takes 0.016 secs on my machine and plotting the result takes the time I needed to type this (61 secs, I'm not a fast typist).

Comment: It's 20000 points. Where did you get 160000 from? Also are you sure the syntax above is correct? I had to abort after 20 minutes of calculation as nothing seemed to be being produced. I can plot a graph of 20000 arbitrary values in about 2 seconds, so something seems wrong to me.

Comment: You stated in the question you had 20^4 rows. But you have 20*10^4 rows instead? I tested the above code line with this random array: `data = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {20^4, 5}];` it works without a problem. Could you put your data set on-line somewhere? One of the problems might be that the data contains non-numerics, like strings.

Comment: I meant to write "You stated in the question you had 20^4 rows. But you have 2*10^4 rows instead?" That takes 2 secs on my machine.

Comment: Sorry I missed the `*10` from my question. I used your random data and the plot came out in about a minute for me too. Could it be there is a problem with how I'm importing or the fact that I have differing ranges in my columns? The ranges are as follows [100,10000] , [2,20], [10^-6, 1], [10^-5, 10^-2], [10^-5, 10^-2].

I'm very sorry but I cannot give the data away.

Comment: Could you try `And @@ NumericQ /@ Flatten[data]` to see if everything is numeric?

Comment: Also I just did the `Transpose` on its own and it did it almost instantly, but the plot just wont happen.

Comment: Back to the drawing-board then. I tried it with the random arrays using the ranges you provided and, though slightly slower at 6 seconds, it still yields a 3D plot in a reasonable time. It might be that the data set has correlations which make it difficult to triangularize. Do you see anything unusual if you plot the data as a series of 2D plots?

Comment: For instance, if the 1st and 4th column are linearly dependent then you don't have a surface but a line.

Comment: I think I'm going to have to do a series of 3D plots for each distinct value in one of my first three columns. I am going to accept your answer since it does what I originally asked for, and I'm going to +1 you for all your help. It's very late here, so I'm going to bed. Perhaps I can come back tomorrow if I have any problems once I've gone 'back to the drawing-board'? Thanks again